# Safe implementation of BufferdReader

Tags: java, security, io, bufferedreader

I want to use a BufferedReader to read a file uploaded to my server.

The file would by written as a CSV file, but I can't assume this, so I code some test where the file is an image or a binary file (supposing the client has sent me the wrong file or an attacker is trying to break my service), or even worse, the file is a valid CSV file but has a line of 100MB.

My application can deal with this problem, but it has to read the first line of the file:

```
...
String firstLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
//Perform some validations and reject the file if it's not a CSV file
...
```

But, when I code some tests, I've found a potential risk: BufferedReader doesn't perform any control over the amount of bytes it reads until it found a return line, so it can ended up throwing an OutOfMemoryError.

This is my test:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import org.junit.Test;

public class BufferedReaderTest {

    @Test(expected=OutOfMemoryError.class)
    public void testReadFileWithoutReturnLineCharacter() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(getInfiniteReader());

        bf.readLine();

        bf.close();
    }

    private Reader getInfiniteReader() {
        return new Reader(){

            @Override
            public int read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) throws IOException {
                return 'A';
            }

            @Override
            public void close() throws IOException {

            }
        };
    }
}
```

I've been looking up some safe BufferedReader implementation on the internet, but I can't find anything. The only class I've found was `BoundedInputStream` from apache IO, that limits the amount of bytes read by an input stream.

I need an implementation of BufferedReader that knows how to limit the number of bytes/characters read **in each line**.

Something like this:

- The app calls 'readLine()'
- The BufferedReader reads bytes until it found a return line character or it reaches the maximum amount of bytes allowed
- If it has found a return line character, then reset the bytes read (so it could read the next line) and return the content
- If it has reached the maximum amount of bytes allowed, it throws an exception

Does anybody knows about an implementation of BufferedReader that has this behaviour?

Comment: Wait, why are you using a `Reader` for binary data? You say you have the "choice" between "an image and a binary file"...

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to improve my question. I'm using a `Reader` because my services is designed to process **only** CSV files. But I have to deal with the situations in witch a client sends me a binary file (accidentally or not). In those cases, my service can reject the file, but it needs to read the first line.

Comment: OK, then I have undeleted my answer. Basically you don't need to "read the first line": just configure a `Reader` appropriately and use a `BufferedReader` over that. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @fge for the answer. I ended up implementing a safe `Reader`that can deal with files with too long lines (or without lines at all).

If anybody wants to see the code, the project (very small project even with many tests) is available here:

https://github.com/jfcorugedo/security-io

Answer (score 2):

This is not how you should proceed to detect whether a file is binary or not.

Here is how you can do to check whether a file is truly text or not; note that this requires that you know the encoding beforehand:

```
final Charset cs = StandardCharsets.UTF_8; // or another

final CharsetDecoder decoder = cs.newDecoder()
    .onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPORT); // default is REPLACE!

// Here, "in" is the input stream from the file
try (
    final Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, decoder);
) {
    final char[] buf = new char[4096]; // or other size
    while (reader.read(buf) != -1)
        ; // nothing
} catch (MalformedInputException e) {
    // cannot decode; binary, or wrong encoding
}
```

Now, since you can initialize a `BufferedReader` over a `Reader`, you can use:

```
try (
    final Reader r = new InputStreamReader(in, decoder);
    final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(r);
) {
    // Read lines normally
} catch (CharacterCodingException e) {
    // Not a CSV, it seems
}

// etc
```

---

Now, a little more explanation about how this works... While this is a fundamenal part of reading text in Java, it is a part which is equally fundamentally misunderstood!

When you read a file as text using a `Reader`, you have to specify a character coding; in Java, this is a `Charset`.

What happens internally is that Java will create a `CharsetDecoder` from that `Charset`, read the `byte` stream and output a `char` stream. And there are three ways to deal with errors:

- `CodingErrorAction.REPLACE` (**the default**): unmappable byte sequences are replaced with the [Unicode replacement character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm) (it does ring a bell, right?);
- `CodingErrorAction.IGNORE`: unmappable byte sequences do not trigger the emission of a `char`;
- `CodingErrorAction.REPORT`: unmappable byte sequences trigger a `CharacterCodingException` to be thrown, which inherits `IOException`; in turn, the two subclasses of `CharacterCodingException` are `MalformedInputException` and `UnmappableCharacterException`.

Therefore, what you need to do in order to detect whether a file is truly text is to:

- know the encoding beforehand!
- use a `CharsetDecoder` configured with `CodingErrorAction.REPORT`;
- use it in an `InputStreamReader`.

This is *one* way; there are others. All of them however will use a `CharsetDecoder` at some point.

Similarly, there is a `CharsetEncoder` for the reverse operation (`char` stream to `byte` stream), and this is what is used by the `Writer` family.

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the question at all. OP is looking for an implementation that, quote: "reads bytes until it [...] or it reaches the maximum amount of bytes allowed"

Comment: @Unihedro Citing the question: "The file would by written as a CSV file, but I can't assume this"

Comment: This may solve the problem of binary file, but what would happen if the file has a line of 100MB of characters? Please, look at my JUnit test. It returns valid characters, but infinite amount of them

Comment: @jfcorugedo if you really want to go this way, don't use a `BufferedReader` then; use a simple `Reader`, a character array buffer and append to a `StringBuilder` as you read.

Comment: All right. I know I can code a solution, but I'd like to use a well-proved implementation (Apache?), but I can't find anything. However, thank you very much, I didn't know about `CodingErrorAction`.

Comment: Well, you can just make your own as you say and make it testable; extend `BufferedReader` and add the maximum line length as an argument. Solutions are many. However, I believe that the "text detection" as it is done by the examples I gave should be largely enough at first ;) Don't try and overengineer it all!